# Redirect post request using nginx

Tags: nginx

I am currently getting post request like this:

```
POST /api/x/y HTTP/1.1
```

With request body: a=x&b=y etc.

I want to redirect the request to another server in any of these two ways:

```
1. GET x.x.x.x:8888/xy/abc?a=x&b=y

2. POST x.x.x.x:8888/xy/abc with body a=x&b=y
```

I am trying these two redirect options:

```
1.rewrite ^(.*) http://server/api$request_body redirect;
//this is not sending body params
2. return 307  http://server/api?$request_body;
//this is giving me 400
```

Comment: Have you tried: `return 307 http://server/api;`. The client should reattempt the POST with the same body.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:8888;
}
```

Then a request to example.com/api/x/y/ will be proxied to http://x.x.x.x:8888/api/x/y/.

If you do this:

```
location /api/x/y/ {
    proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:8888/xy/abc/;
}
```

Then a request to example.com/api/x/y/ will be proxied to http://x.x.x.x:8888/xy/abc/.

Request method will be unchanged, unless you tell Nginx to change it. Some headers will not be passed, unless you tell Nginx to pass them.